# Why is setState returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to close a modal when a user presses outside of the Modal element. Somehow when `Dismiss()` is called, the state is still the same in the callback.

Why is this happening?

```
export default class Message extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: "",
            show: false
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.onRef(this);
    }

    Show(id) {
        this.setState({
            id: id,
            show: true
        });
    }

    Dismiss() {
        this.setState({
            id: '',
            show: false
        }, function (state) {
            console.log(state) // undefined
        });
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.show) {
            return (
                <Modal close={() => this.Dismiss()}>
                    <h1>{this.state.id}</h1>
                </Modal>
            );
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure why there's a state argument in your callback, should just be

```
Dismiss() {
    this.setState({
        id: '',
        show: false
    }, function () {
        console.log(this.state)
    });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, that is because `this.setState` function in React is `async`. And the new state is only available in the `event queue`

Here is what I mean:

```
this.setState({newAdded: "test"});
let youCannotGetIt = this.state.newAdded; // here is undefined, because this.setSate is async
```